# unable to increment the text view value while clicking a button .. its updating only when changing from one tab to another

Tags: java, android, android-activity, import

**Helper Class**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class HelperActivity extends Activity {
        String btnvariable, tempcount;
        SharedPreferences preferences;
        Configuration config;
        boolean temp;
        DataBaseHandler db;
        static int count;
        NewBreakfastItems bitems;

        public static TextView num;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.footer);
            preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            tempcount = preferences.getString("count1", "");

        }

        public void footerBlock() {
            Log.e("", "footer block-----");

            Log.e("---helper count---", "" + count);
            Log.d("", "count from items class" + "\t" + NewBreakfastItems.count1);
            count = NewBreakfastItems.getVariable();
            Log.e("---helper count---", "====y value====" + count);


            // temp = true;

            final TextView btn_about = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.about);
            final TextView btn_recipe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipe);
            final TextView btn_chef = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chef);
            final TextView btn_signin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signin);
            final TextView num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num);
            final TextView btn_urorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.urorders);

            /* num.setText(NewBreakfastItems.count1); */
            // Log.e("--contacts--", "-----count----"+db.getContactsCount());

            if (!getPref("pref__count").equals("")) {
                Log.e("", "getPref------" + getPref("pref__count"));
                num.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            }
            if (!tempcount.equals("")) {
                Log.e("", "tempcount-----" + tempcount);
                int countnew = db.getContactsCount();
                num.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                // num.setText(countnew);
            }

            if (getPref("pref__footer").equals("btn_about")) {

                btn_about.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ED2C2F"));
                btn_recipe.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_chef.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_signin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_urorders.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                num.setText(String.valueOf(count));

            } else if (getPref("pref__footer").equals("btn_recipe")) {

                btn_recipe.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ED2C2F"));
                btn_about.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_chef.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_signin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_urorders.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                num.setText(String.valueOf(count));

            } else if (getPref("pref__footer").equals("btn_chef")) {

                btn_chef.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ED2C2F"));
                btn_about.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_recipe.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_signin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_urorders.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                num.setText(String.valueOf(count));

            } else if (getPref("pref__footer").equals("btn_signin")) {

                btn_signin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ED2C2F"));
                btn_about.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_recipe.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_chef.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_urorders.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                num.setText(String.valueOf(count));

            }

            else if (getPref("pref__footer").equals("btn_urorders")) {

                btn_urorders.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ED2C2F"));
                btn_about.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_recipe.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_chef.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                btn_signin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                num.setText(String.valueOf(count));

            }

            btn_about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // btn_about.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

                    PrefEdit("pref__footer", "btn_about");

                    // PrefEdit("pref__footer", "btn_about");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            btn_recipe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    PrefEdit("pref__footer", "btn_recipe");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Menu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            btn_chef.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    PrefEdit("pref__footer", "btn_chef");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(HelperActivity.this,
                            YourOrder.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            });

        }

        public static void getcount() {

            num.setText(String.valueOf(count));

            // return;

        }

        /*
         * public void count() { count = count + 1; num.setText(count); }
         */
        public String getPref(String key) {
            String pref_value = preferences.getString(key, "");
            return pref_value;
        }

        public void PrefEdit(String key, String val) {
            Editor edit = preferences.edit();
            edit.putString(key, val);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }
```

**Items Adapter**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.renderscript.Script.LaunchOptions;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewBreakfastItems extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] menulist;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    private final Integer[] prices;
    public int count = 0;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    HelperActivity help;
    public static int count1;

    public DataBaseHandler db;

    public NewBreakfastItems(Activity context, String[] menu1,
            Integer[] imageId, Integer[] prices) {
        super(context, R.layout.breakfastitems, menu1);
        this.context = context;
        this.menulist = menu1;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.prices = prices;
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "ViewHolder", "InflateParams" })
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.breakfastitems, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.recipetitle);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.recipeimage);
        TextView pricetxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.recipeprice);
        Button order = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.order);
        final TextView numtxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.num);

        // numtxt.setText("1");

        txtTitle.setText(menulist[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        // pricetxt.setText(prices[position]);
        pricetxt.setText(Integer.toString(prices[position]));
        // Log.e("", "==Item==" + menulist[position] + "Price" +
        // prices[position]);

        db = new DataBaseHandler(getContext());
        // count= db.getContactsCount();

        /* ==========ADDING RECIPES TO DATABASE======= */
        order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // db.getWritableDatabase();

                imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
                // Log.i("Bitmap value ================", bitmap.toString());
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                // Log.d("", "=====menulist====="+menulist[position]);
                db.addContact(new Contact(menulist[position], imageInByte));

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),menulist[position] + "\t"+ "inserted sucessfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.d("----------", "======INSERTED========"
                        + menulist[position]);
                db.getContactsCount();
                Log.d("", "==count==" + db.getContactsCount());
                count1 = db.getContactsCount();
                //help.PrefEdit("pref__count", count1 + "");
                Log.d("", "==count1==" + count1);
                //HelperActivity.count();

            }

        });

        /*preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        // count=10;
        help.PrefEdit("pref__count", count1 + "");*/

        return rowView;

    }
    public static int getVariable()
    {
        Log.i("", "---count1---"+count1);
        return count1;
    }



}



This is my Helperclass code which is used for tab indication... i need to to update the textview at the tabbar when clicking a button order in the NewBreakfastItems.java class...
```

i am getting the result value from the newbreakfast class and setting it in textview of footerclass but problem is i am not getting the setting result value into the text view immediately
pleaase help me
Thank you in advance....

Comment: for what purpose did you use the `NewBreakfastItems` class.

Comment: I am using this for displaying list of recipes. In this list i am able to order the recipes and those recipes are added into the db. But when i am clicking order button the text value not immediately changes

Comment: When you click the button in `NewBreakfastItems` class,update the text view in `HelperActivity ` am right.

Comment: yes obsolutely i need that

Comment: Simple solution is pass the `text-view` as an argument,like you pass the `prices` array.Set value for the text-view when button click in `NewBreakfastItems` class.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the **Text-view** as argument like you passed the **Price** array:-

**HelperActivity.class**

```
TextView num;
NewBreakfastItems bitems = new  NewBreakfastItems(HelperActivity.this,menu1,imageId,prices,num);
```

**NewBreakfastItems.class**

```
private final Activity context;
private final String[] menulist;
private final Integer[] imageId;
private final Integer[] prices;
TextView num;

public NewBreakfastItems(Activity context, String[] menu1,Integer[] imageId, Integer[] prices,TextView tv_num) {
    super(context, R.layout.breakfastitems, menu1);
    this.context = context;
    this.menulist = menu1;
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.prices = prices;
    this.num = tv_num;
}
```

**Inside onClick**

```
num = "Some text what you need";
```

Comment: I want to set the db count in the text value. This text value is at the footer tab. I create a nethos in newbreakfastitems class and getting count from the db and setting that value to textview its works perfectly

Comment: But the issue is while intially launching the app the text value shows zero if i add another recipe to db it shows previousvalue+present value at a time

Comment: did you check the DB file with some external tools.Put log inside the `onCreate` with `db.getcount();` say it will get the count or not.

Comment: I am perfectly getting the textview updation through db.getcount() but i am trying t insert one more feild in DB but its not working

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    contact.setImage(cursor.getBlob(2));
    contact.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));// I am getting error in this line
contactList.add(contact);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }  db.close();
  
return contactList;
}

Comment: I am getting error at contact.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)))

Comment: I created new row... but so much time i struggled with that error..  it works perfectly yesterday when i am launching the eclipse again it shows an error at new row creation

Comment: @yamuna i think its not a problem with eclipse.first thing i want say is ask the question in precise way.Now your problem is fetch data from **DB** or Insert the data into **DB** but you ask the question like problem in text-view that's why someone put down vote.if possible send the code to my mail id I'll check it and revert back to you or update **DB** coding in your question.